# cvLoadImage for IplImage working, but cv::imread for cv::Mat not workign

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I am facing a weird issue where I am unable to read a basic image file from the filesystem using `cv::imread`. Hence the below results into imageInput having null data, with rows and cols set to 0.

```
cv::Mat imageInput =  cv::Mat();
imageInput = cv::imread("abc.jpg",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Interestingly, after commenting out the above code, the below code is able to read the iamge:

```
//cv::Mat imageInput =  cv::Mat();
//imageInput = cv::imread("abc.jpg",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
IplImage *rImg;
rImg = cvLoadImage("abc.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

`rImg` gets a width of 3296, and height of 2256 as expected.
I am clueless how this is possible. Please help.
The build seems to be fine in both cases. I tried using both opencv-2.4.5 and opencv-2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to figure out the issue now.
The issue was mention of release build static libraries instead of debug-build static libraries.
Earlier for the VC++ project, I was including the following lib dependencies in debug mode : `opencv_core245.lib;opencv_highgui245.lib;opencv_imgproc245.lib;opencv_video245.lib`

Upon changing it to `opencv_core245d.lib;opencv_highgui245d.lib;opencv_imgproc245d.lib;opencv_video245d.lib`, I am able to read images using imread without any issues.